# C# Query returns adapter properties rather than table data

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding, datagridview, datatable

Please see code below...

```
        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable workTable = new DataTable("PingMonitorData");
        var dgvAlarmsBindingSource = new BindingSource();
        var cs = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        cs.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=SERVER_NAME\INSTANCE_NAME;Initial Catalog=PingMonitorSQL;Integrated Security=True";
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT EmailAddress, FullName, AlertGroup FROM AlertRecipients",cs.ConnectionString))
        {
            dgvAlarms.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            dgvAlarms.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            da.Fill(workTable);
            dgvAlarmsBindingSource.DataSource = da;
            dgvAlarms.DataSource = dgvAlarmsBindingSource;
        }
    }
```

This fills the DGV with, what looks to me like, the properties of the table adapter? The test DB has one row in the table, one email address, one name and one value for alert group.

Any help will be tremendous.

[Screenshot - Properties Rather Than Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk9nt.png)

Be as critical as you like, this is my first C# program so it's probably a mess.

Comment: You should set the _workTable_ variable as the DataSource of your dgvAlarmsBindingSource

Comment: `dgvAlarmsBindingSource.DataSource = da;`, was that supposed to be `dgvAlarmsBindingSource.DataSource = workTable;`?

Comment: Thats what comes from copy and paste! Thanks people, that has fixed my issue.